# PHP Late Static Binding for non static calls

Tags: php

I could use some clarification to the code snippet below.  Although I don't have any static methods defined can I still take advantage of LSB and are there any issues with how I'm creating the object in the start call?  The start call works as expected when I use new static() but I want to ensure I'm not shooting myself in the foot somehow.

```
class Person
{

    public function doStuff()
    {
        echo "Person doing stuff";
    }

    public function start()
    {
        $person = new static();
        //$person = new self();
        $person->doStuff();
    }
}

class CrazyPerson extends Person
{

    public function doStuff()
    {
        echo "CrazyPerson doing stuff";
    }
}

$s = new CrazyPerson();
$s->start();
```

Comment: The code you use makes no sense. You can only call `start()` if you have an instance of either `Person` or `CrazyPerson` - why do you create another instance, call a public method on this and then forget the instance? I'd simply call `doStuff()` right away.

Comment: I do have an object that I call start on, see end of the code sample.  The pattern is a bit odd I agree but can't change that for now, working with a code base I didn't write.